# TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file

Tags: php, tcpdf

I keep receiving this error when trying to add my own array into the code.
Here is my array;

```
$array = array();

while (odbc_fetch_row($rs))
{
    $array[] = odbc_result($rs,'Product Name');
}
 
$test = print_r($array);
```

The original code is here. I'm using an example page to try it because I know the example page works fine.

http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_001.phps

This code is before the $html variable and when it is set I just add the $test variable into the $html variable. The odbc connection works fine and the example works fine before I add any code but when I run the script I get this error;

```
Array ( [0] => Test1 [1] => Test2 ) TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file
```

And there is also more than 2 items in the Array. Any ideas?

Comment: Was there any outbut before headers were sent? Is it UTF-8 file? Is it UTF-8 without BOM file?

Comment: have tried changing the variable names of `$test` and `$array`?

Comment: You get this error because you want to print out something before the pdf headers are sent, comment the pdf part for debug and then use them

Comment: If you want to have the return value of [`print_r`](http://php.net/print_r) you need the second parameter: `$test = print_r($array, true);`

Comment: Hi @CORRUPT I'm not sure exactly what you mean about the headers, There shouldent be any output because I have put the $test variable into the Code that generates the HTML part, I believe it is UTF-8

Comment: I added the true parameter and it has worked! Thank you @DanLee for your help. Thank you all for your help and comments!

Comment: Try this :
ob_end_clean();

Answer (score 58):

Add the function ob_end_clean(); before call the Output function.
It worked for me within a custom Wordpress function!

```
ob_end_clean();
$pdf->Output($pdf_name, 'I');
```

Answer (score 40):

Just use  ob_start(); at the top of the page.

Comment: LITERALLY AT THE TOP OF THE PAGE.. who codes in this PHP anymore anyhow!?

Answer (score 10):

Add the function ob_end_clean() before call the Output function.

Comment: I have a pdf generator that works fine in some server or fire errors in others, nothing clear because I have no white spaces at beginning or just after `<?php`, I have no closer tag because is a pure php file, and I have no errors output. Using `ob_end_clean()` just before `$pdf->Output($data, 'D')` everything works fine.

Answer (score 9):

I just want to add that I was getting this error, and nothing would fix it until I changed the `Output` destination parameter from `F` to `FI`.
In other words, I have to output to both file and inline.

```
Output('doc.pdf', 'I')
```

to

```
Output('doc.pdf', 'FI')
```

I have no idea why this made the difference, but it fixed the error for me...

Comment: Yes ! Worked with php7.0.10 and Html2PDF 4.03

Answer (score 6):

This problem means you have headers. Deletes tags

> ?>

at the end of your code and make sure not to have whitespace at the beginning.

Comment: it means, content has already been sent. So the headers cannot be set anymore

Answer (score 4):

The tcpdf file that causes the "data has already been output" is in the tcpdf folder called tcpdf.php. You can modify it:

add the line **ob_end_clean();** as below (3rd last line):

```
public function Output($name='doc.pdf', $dest='I') {
    //LOTS OF CODE HERE....}
    switch($dest) {
        case 'I': {
        // Send PDF to the standard output
        if (ob_get_contents()) {
        $this->Error('Some data has already been output, can\'t send PDF file');}
        //some code here....}
            case 'D': {         // download PDF as file
        if (ob_get_contents()) {
    $this->Error('Some data has already been output, can\'t send PDF file');}
            break;}
        case 'F':
        case 'FI':
        case 'FD': {
            // save PDF to a local file
                 //LOTS OF CODE HERE.....       break;}
        case 'E': {
            // return PDF as base64 mime email attachment)
        case 'S': {
            // returns PDF as a string
            return $this->getBuffer();
        }
        default: {
            $this->Error('Incorrect output destination: '.$dest);
        }
    }
           ob_end_clean(); //add this line here 
    return '';
}
```

Now lets look at your code.
I see you have $rs and $sql mixed up. These are 2 different things working together.

```
$conn=odbc_connect('northwind','****','*****');
if (!$conn) {
   exit("Connection Failed: " . $conn);
 }

$sql="SELECT * FROM products"; //is products your table name?
$rs=odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
if (!$rs) {
  exit("Error in SQL");
}

while (odbc_fetch_row($rs)) {
  $prodname=odbc_result($rs,"Product Name"); //but preferably never use spaces for table names.
 $prodid=odbc_result($rs,"ProdID");  //prodID is assumed attribute
  echo "$prodname";
  echo "$prodid";
}
odbc_close($conn);

now you can use the $prodname and output it to the TCPDF output.
```

and I assume your are connecting to a MS access database.

Answer (score 4):

Use ob_start(); at the beginning of your code.

Answer (score 3):

The error of "Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file" refers to the output buffer of PHP.

so you need to clean any content of the output buffer before sending output.

```
ob_end_clean(); // Clean any content of the output buffer
```

then

```
$pdf->Output('example_001.pdf', 'I'); // Send the PDF !
```

Answer (score 2):

for my case Footer method was having malformed html code (missing td) causing error on osx.

```
public function Footer() {
$this->SetY(-40);
$html = <<<EOD
<table>
<tr>
 Test Data
</tr>
</table>
EOD;
$this->writeHTML($html);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use 
ob_end_clean();

$pdf->Output($file, 'I'); 
to open pdf.
It works for me

Answer (score 2):

I had this but unlike the OP I couldn't see any output before the TCPDF error message.

Turns out there was a UTF8 BOM (byte-order-mark) at the very start of my script, before the <?php tag so before I had any chance to call ob_start(). And there was also a UTF8 BOM before the TCPDF error message.

Answer (score 2):

I had this weird error
and the culprit is a white space on the beginning of the PHP open tag

even without the `ob_flush` and `ob_end_clean`

Just make sure there are no extra `white spaces` on or after any `<?php ?>` block

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error but finally I solved it by suppressing PHP errors
Just put this code `error_reporting(0);` at the top of your print page

```
    <?php 
    error_reporting(0); //hide php errors
    if( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
    require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/tohtml/tcpdf/tcpdf.php';
    .... //continue
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem is when `apache/php` show errors.

This data(`html`) destroy pdf output.

You must off display errors in **php.ini**.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are still facing this issue try adding:

`libxml_use_internal_errors(true);`

before the `loadHtml` call and add

`libxml_use_internal_errors(false);`

after the call.

This solved it for me.

Comment: Which loadHtml call?