# show loading image while pdf page loads

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, pdf, tcpdf

pdf.php

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
        $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
    })
</script>
<div class="loader" style=" position: fixed;
                            left: 0px;
                            top: 0px;
                            width: 100%;
                            height: 100%;
                            z-index: 2;
                            background: url('http://bradsknutson.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/page-loader.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat rgb(249,249,249);">
</div>


<?php
require_once('pdf/tcpdf_include.php');

...lot of code here...

$pdf->Output('file.pdf', 'I');
?>
```

i have a working code that creates pdf and i want to have a loading image while pdf page loads but i cant seem to figure out how to do that. i currently have the above code.

thanks in advance guys...

Comment: possible duplicate of [TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16011050/tcpdf-error-some-data-has-already-been-output-cant-send-pdf-file)