# A non-numeric value encountered php 7 tcpdf

Tags: php, tcpdf

```
$header_x = (float)$this->original_lMargin + (float)($headerdata['logo_width'] * (float)1.1);
```

> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: A non-numeric value encountered
>
> Filename: tcpdf/tcpdf.php
>
> Line Number: 3422

Comment: Check by printing all values before this statement. You will get to know which value is non-numeric

Comment: convert to all value numeric type casting throught but not slow

Comment: If any value is in string format you can't convert it to float

Comment: one variable value in blank

Comment: Then you should check all the values before casting them in float

Answer (score 0):

I worked on this issue many days. In my case, I solved this problem on this way:

When you create a PDF with tcpdf you need to use `ob_start();` at the top, then create instance object :

```
$pdf = new pdf(PDF_PAGE_ ..... BODY.. FOOTER, ETC,
```

and before output :

```
$pdf->Output('/media/Linux/Folder/document.pdf', 'F')
```

You need to end your ob with:

```
ob_end_clean();
```

I realised about the problem from create two or more PDFs continuously. You could try this.

I found the answer while visiting this:

[TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16011050/tcpdf-error-some-data-has-already-been-output-cant-send-pdf-file/35951509)